# Replicating Script Behavior in Templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am currently trying to build a website using a `header.html` template included in an `index.html` file.

I currently have the template working. I had been using jQuery Rotate (http://jqueryrotate.com/) to make the logo flip upside down on a mouseover.

Since Angular won't allow `<script>` tags in templates for security reasons I was wondering what the standard practice is to replicate script behaviors. I can still use `ng-mouseover` and `ng-mouseleave`. Is there a convenient way to call the jQuery Rotate functions from my controller?

Comment: Could you show us some code, perhaps a file structure? Any reason you're using JQuery Rotate over Angular Routing (which does partials like this)?

Comment: Templates are what I have been familiar with in the past, so it is what I gravitated toward it. How does routing work differently and does it help with scripting like this?

Comment: Tempting does work, Angular Routing is just more popular and follows Angular's paradigm. Essentially, it allows you to have one parent view, with inner-nested ng-views that show partials. 

Aside from this, what does your code right now look like? Specifically, your controller.